# Extend the Nightwatch internal Logger

Tags: nightwatch.js

nightwatch commands use a class named Logger to log the messages as the commands are executed. Is there a way to extend this logger?

I would like to capture Every message submitted to the Logger by the nightwatch client and do something else to it.

In my case I want to submitt the messages to the "attach" function in cucumber-js so nightwatch logs can be "Attached" to cucumber-js reports.

Is there a Logger Handler or Logger Consumer or Logger Listener or something like that ? 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually not every message nightwatch outputs to the console goes though the Logger. Assertions for example print directly to console via console.log instead of being pushed to the Logger first as a trace message and let the listeners decide what to do with it.  (Look for assert.js line 205 in their repositoy)

Currently the logging infrastructure doesn't have the concept of Listeners like log4net. This shouldn't be the case specially for a tool used for  integration tests that will run inside build servers. Be able to control its logs output is of paramount importance. You can have a log listener that will output to console with colors using special characters, another that will output the logs as normal text for non color terminals (no crazy characters displayed). Another developed by a user that will attach log messages to cucumber reports or format them to be displayed in a jira confluence page for the release notes and so on.